# discord.py Spotify doesnt seem to do anything

Tags: python, discord.py, spotify

I'm developing my first bot just as a hobby and something to help me learn some Python and I've been trying to integrate Spotify with it but it just doesn't seem to work. I also read the other post on this website but it did not help.

I have tried reading through the documentation but I am a beginner and could not find much on google to help.

if I do print(discord.Spotify.title), I get this <property object at 0x0000020E42C5DE00>

This is the code I tried to use but did not work:

```py
from discord import Spotify

@bot.command()
async def spotify(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
        pass
    if user.activities:
        for activity in user.activities:
            if isinstance(activity, Spotify):
                embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{user.name}'s Spotify", description = "Listening to{}".format(activity.title), color = 0xC902FF)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=activity.album_cover_url)
                embed.add_field(name="Artist", value=activity.artist)
                embed.add_field(name="Album", value=activity.album)
                embed.set_footer(text="Song started at {}".format(activity.created_at.strftime("%H:%M")))
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Apologies for any formatting issues. Not sure if I used the code block correctly

I am also using cogs if it makes a difference at all.

Just want it to at least send me back a message with the song the user is playing so I can have it respond differently to different artists or songs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to check if it is a problem with your Intents. Import `all` with the following function:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Connected with a code the following command works fine for me:

```py
from discord import Spotify

@bot.command()
async def spotify(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
        pass
    if user.activities:
        for activity in user.activities:
            if isinstance(activity, Spotify):
                embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{user.name}'s Spotify", description = "Listening to{}".format(activity.title), color = 0xC902FF)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=activity.album_cover_url)
                embed.add_field(name="Artist", value=activity.artist)
                embed.add_field(name="Album", value=activity.album)
                embed.set_footer(text="Song started at {}".format(activity.created_at.strftime("%H:%M")))
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**The output:**

[image]

Comment: Nope, still nothing. I'm not sure what the problem could be because my Spotify is open and playing and I've tried the code in both a cog and in main.py but no response in Discord or error printed in the console. All my other commands work so I have no clue what's going on. In a cog all I did was change it commands.command instead of bot.command

Comment: Have you also activated that people can see what you are playing on Spotify? (`Shortcuts -> Show Spotify as your status`) If you use `commands.command`/Cogs you can try to edit the command to the following: `async def spotify(self, ctx, user: discord.Member = None):` - Maybe that is/was the problem.

Comment: Yep Spotify is showing as my status but still nothing. I also added self to that but still nothing. If my code is correct, I wonder where else the problem can be.

Comment: Did you indented the code correctly? You can also add a `#` to individual fields and see if one of the `fields` causes the error.

Comment: Okay so I've done some testing. Not sure if I did this correctly but if I tell it to `print(user.activities)` the console shows just `()` It doesn't matter what my status is (spotify, nothing, easyRP) the output doesn't change. Could this be a permissions issue? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried granting your bot a different role with more permissions? `activities` does not need any permissions I get. If you import all the Intents and activated them in the Discord Developer Portal you should be fine.

Comment: Nope, still nothing, unfortunately. I tried a different role and I also readded the bot as an admin. Really confused here. Spotify is playing and showing up in my status as well.

Comment: What is your whole code? Just paste a link with the code

Comment: Looks like `pass_context=True` is missing

Comment: Nope still nothing

Comment: You can remove the link again, token can be seen. I have the commands screenshotted, will take a look at it. Are the other commands working?

Comment: Have you activated the `Presence` Intent and imported that?

Comment: Ah shoot I completely forgot about the token, thanks. Okay so I enabled the presence thing from the Discord Developer website. What's the code to import it?

Comment: I will edit my question for that, you forgot to import them all.

Comment: Hey never mind, I got it working lol. I used `intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents.members = True` and added `intents=intents` to the line with the prefix. Thank you so much for your help I was stumped for a while now on this!

Comment: No problem. Have fun with the command and do not forget to accept the answer if it all in all helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

After adding this line:

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
```

you need to add intents to the bot parameter:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "?", intents=intents)
```