# Why is the current Spotify song not displayed?

Tags: discord.py, spotify

So I want to create a command/feature where it sends a lyric from the song ur playing (i'll have these in a list for specific songs). But where I get stuck is were I have to work with the Spotify library/module thing, I am not getting errors but I'm not getting results either, it all just stays blank.

**Here's my code for the spotify command:**

```py
from discord import Spotify  

@bot.command()
async def spotify1(ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    user = user or ctx.author
    for activity in user.activities:
        if isinstance(activity, Spotify):
            await ctx.send(f"{user} is listening to {activity.title} by {activity.artist}")
            print(activity.title)
            print('im working')
```

Does anyone see a mistake here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py Spotify doesnt seem to do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67052222/discord-py-spotify-doesnt-seem-to-do-anything)

Comment: Hi Dominik, if i add intents=intents to the prefix line, i get a huge chunk of text in my terminal(one big error) any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Are you aware that your indents are a bit messed up?

Comment: yea it did that while pasting in the stackoverflow site, but ill double check to be sure

Comment: @ErikN118 Enable them in the Discord Developer Portal, I guess. The error should tell you what to do.

Comment: ill try, what do you mean by 'them'?

Comment: The intents have to be enabled in the Discord Developer Portal before importing them into your code.

Comment: you should know, the bot has administrator permission checked

Comment: Dominik, you truly are a god

Comment: it works now . .

Comment: btw, is there a way to let the bot perform an action when the song changes? or for the bot to detect that the song has changed without making it check every 1 sec orso for wich song is playing?

Comment: This may be possible, yes, you can check out the docs for that or do some research. :)

Comment: can you send link to that doc?